# Azure Mobile Service - Facebook logout

Tags: c#, facebook, azure

I created .NET app with Azure Mobile Service Facebook Authentication. I used credential:

```
// Login with the identity provider.
        user = await App.MobileService
            .LoginAsync(provider);

        // Create and store the user credentials.
        credential = new PasswordCredential(provider,
            user.UserId, user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
        vault.Add(credential);
```

How do log off ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [MobileServiceClient.Logout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.logout.aspx).

This method clears any cookies set by the identity provider before calling the **MobileServiceClient.Logout** method to log the user out of the Azure Mobile Services instance.

The following code example shows the Logout method for the iOS platform:

```
public void Logout()
{
  foreach (var cookie in NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies) {
    NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.DeleteCookie (cookie);
  }

  App.Client.Logout ();
}
```

Code for the Android platform:

```
public void Logout ()
{
  CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie ();
  App.Client.Logout ();
}
```

Code for the Windows Phone 8.1 platform:

```
public void Logout()
{
  ...
  AzureTodo.App.Client.Logout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MobileServiceClient.Logout

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.logout.aspx